# How to disable "New From Existing" functionality of Powerpoint programatically?

Tags: vsto, add-in, powerpoint-2010

I have written VSTO addin for Powerpoint 2010. 
I want to disable "New From Exisiting" functionality for powerpoint to achive some requirements.
This option comes under :
File -> New -> New From Existing

So is there any way to block or disable this functionality through code or registry settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hooked CBTProc method of Windows in my plugin. In CBTProc we can capture every dialog box. So I have written code on this method by capturing call of "New from Existing Presentation" dialog box.
You can get more info on CBTProc here :
[CBTProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the built-in tab or button on the backstage in PowerPoint 2010 and add your own control instead if required. Read more about the Backstage UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks Eugene for reply. 

I tried some code using Control Ids. But using that i can disable whole group buttons.

But i need to perform some functionality on one specific option of that group. But i'm not able to do that.

For e.g
<command idMso="GroupNewFormTemplates" enabled="false"/>

using this whole template group got disabled. But I just want to disable "New from Existing" option of this group. 

Even I didn't able to find Control ID for this option.

So can you please help me in this scenario in detail ??